# Can a chrome extension access a webcam?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have done some research about deloping for chrome. Is it true that only apps (not extensions) accsess the webcam?

Comment: did you solve this? I'm trying to do the same.

Comment: I believe you'll find the answer you are looking for here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74132558/how-to-access-webcam-in-a-chrome-extension/74132795#74132795

Comment: I believe that you will find the answer you are looking for here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74132795/20286745

Answer (score 4):

Any web page can access the webcam (with user permission) via the HTML5 getUserMedia API as long as it has the https protocol.

https://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera

That would include extensions, apps, and ordinary web pages.

Comment: tried to add permission to videoCapture in the manifest, it worked for apps but not for extension...